# Infinite direct sum of $l_q$ spaces is isometricallly isomorphic to $l_q$?

Tags: banach-spaces, direct-sum

In my lectures, it was stated but not proved that

$$\bigoplus _{i\geq 1} l_q \cong l_q$$

meaning that the infinite direct sum of $l_q$ sequnce spaces is isometrically isomorphic to $l_q$. But I don't see how this can be the case. In particular, all elements $x \in l_q$ have $\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^q = a < \infty$. But now having a direct sum of these spaces, we have no guarantee that the infinite sum $\Sigma |a_i| $ is $< infty$.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you are missing that the direct some allows non-zero entries only for finitely many indices.

Comment: @Al-HasanIbnAl-Hasan Is this part of the genera definition of direct sum, or only in this context?

Comment: It is general. The other concept is product (usually denoted $\Pi$).

Answer (score 0):

Split $\mathbb N$ into countably many infinite sets $\Gamma_n$, say. The space

$$\ell_p(\Gamma_n)= \{f\in \ell_p(\mathbb N)\colon f|_{\mathbb N\setminus \Gamma_n} = 0\}$$

is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_p$. For each $n$ let $T_n\colon \ell_p \to \ell_p(\Gamma_n)$ that arises from a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\Gamma_n$. The map $T\colon \ell_p \to (\bigoplus_n \ell_p)_{\ell_p}$ given by

$$Tf = (T_n (f|_{\Gamma_n}))_{n=1}^\infty$$

is the sought isometry. (Requires checking.)

Comment: Hi! I remembered that my lecturer had mentioned that only finitely many of the elements in the direct sum are non-zero, so in this case the resolution is that given by $\epsilon - o$ below (deleted). But I am really interested in what you have done above. I'm not quite sure what it is saying though. It certainly isn't true that the direct sum of l_p spaces is isometrically isomorphic to l_p if we don't make some restriction.